# MobX and observation of an object and its properties which is a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I don't know if I can present my problem clearly and legibly.
Let me start by introducing...

### ...the essence

I have created a Mobx store, where I store information about dialog boxes. It is very simple, so let me quote it in full here.

```
import { makeObservable, action, computed, observable } from "mobx";

class WindowsStore {
    windowsList = [];

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            windowsList: observable,
            addWindow: action,
            removeWindowById: action,
            windows: computed,
        });
    }

    addWindow(uniqueId, component, props) {
        this.windowsList.push({ 
            id: uniqueId,
            Win: [component],
            props
        });
    }

    removeWindowById(wndId) {
        const wndIndex = this.windowsList.findIndex((wnd) => wnd.id === wndId);
        if (wndIndex > -1) this.windowsList.splice(wndIndex, 1);
    }

    get windows() {
        return this.windowsList; <-- is't sick, but I don't like mobx strict-mode warnings
    }
}

const windowsStore = (window.windowsStore = new WindowsStore());

export default windowsStore;
```

I wanted such a construction, because it needs to place all dialogs as children in one component (I will present it below)

```
const WindowsList = observer(({ windowsStore }) => {
    return windowsStore.windows.map((wnd) => {
        const Win = wnd.Win[0]; <-- it's weird (I know it) but that's the only way it wants to work
        return (
            <Win
                {...wnd.props}
                key={wnd.id}
                onClose={() => {
                    WindowsStore.removeWindowById(wnd.id);
                }}
            />
        );
    });
});
```

then, calls the component `<WindowsList windowsStore = {WindowsStore} />` where it needs and voilà.

Now, anywhere in the application, it calls store `addWindow (uniqueId, component_class, props)` to call the dialog.

What happens next. The variable `props` (generally as an object) is passed as properties to `component_class` (as seen in the body of the `<WindowsList />` component above)

Indeed, it works.

### My problem

However, I have a problem with passing a function in props, e.g .:

```
// ...somewhere in dialog component...
    doDelete(e) {
        console.log("Deleting...");
    }

    openDeleteConfirm = (item) => {
        const filepath = combinePathName(item.path, item.name);
        WindowsStore.addWindow("delete-" + filepath, DeleteConfirmation, {
            item: filepath,
            onConfirm: this.doDelete, <-- this is my problem :(
        });
    };
```

What I noticed is that, there is no `onConfirm` property passed in the dialog component, even though it is visible in `store.windowsList`. Here is the console output:

```
> windowsStore.windowsList[0].props
Proxy {Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration, onConfirm: ƒ}
    [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Object
        item: (...)
        onConfirm: ƒ res() <-- Here!
        Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration {target_: {…}, values_: Map(1), name_: "WindowsStore@206.windowsList[..].props", keysAtom_: Atom, defaultEnhancer_: ƒ, …}
        get item: ƒ ()
        set item: ƒ (v)
        __proto__: Object
    [[IsRevoked]]: false
```

How can I pass a function via store to a component as its property?
Is it even possible?

Help, because I got lost a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

### It's not a solution

In part, I managed to fix my problem, however it is imprecise and I am afraid it may cause other problems (in the future)

### The trick

I decided to put a pointer to an action in the `actions` array like this:

```
// ...somewhere in dialog component...

    doDelete({ path, name }) {
        console.log(`Delete entry ${name} in ${path}...`);
    }

    openDeleteConfirm = (item) => {
        const filepath = combinePathName(item.path, item.name);
        WindowsStore.addWindow("delete-" + filepath, DeleteConfirmation, {
            item: filepath,
            actions: [
                () => {
                    this.doDelete(item);
                },
            ],
        });
    };
```

In the dialog code, referenced by index in the `actions` array:

```js
    this.props.actions[0]();
```

It works, but I don't like it: /